# Why BigQuery table last modified date does not match to the last insert date?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

BigQuery table last modified date does not match at the last insert date. I set up a Cloud Schedulers to stream data every day into BigQuery. All records have a creation date, initialized at the time data is inserted. However, the "last modified" date of the table is not the same. Nothing else manipulate the table excepted read operations.

**Why the dates are not the same?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: It is very productive to be downvoted without explanation. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

When using the streaming method to insert to BigQuery, the data is kept into a streaming buffer, and later will be fully flushed to the BigQuery storage layer. The later date could be this effect as well, or you've done some other mods on the table like label, description etc...